# Intercept UITapGestureRecognizer for UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm trying to figure out how to intercept a click event on a `UIWebView`.  It seems like the correct gesture is `UITapGestureRecognizer`, but I can't seem to get the view right.  I haven't been able to find a solution in swift.  My hierarchy is `View -> UIWebView`.  My use case is to deploy a web app and have some custom actions based on the web view navigation.  For example, being able to recognize navigation events in which I'd want to serve an interstitial ad or display a `UINavigationBar`.  Thanks for any help!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet var Webview: UIWebView!

   let URLPath = "http://www.example.com"

   func loadAddressURL(){

       let requestURL = NSURL(string: URLPath)
       let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
       Webview.loadRequest(request)

   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       loadAddressURL()
       NSLog("I'm getting going")        

       //NOT SURE IF YOU SHOULD DISABLE THIS OR NOT
       //Webview.userInteractionEnabled=false


       let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self , action: "handleSingleTap:")
       NSLog("I'm past the tab recognizer!\(tapRecognizer)")

       tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
       Webview.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   func handleSingleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
       //
       NSLog("I made it here")
   }   

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

first set Gesture Delegate  and inherited geture **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate**

```
tapRecognizer.delegate = self
```

and Insert this delegate

```
func gestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer,  shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool 
{
    return true
}
```

Try this maybe help-full...

Comment: I changed the class definition line to `class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {` in addition to the other code you wrote and now it's working.  Thanks!