# how to add tap gesture recognizer on UIWebView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I want insert tap gesture recognizer on `UIWebView` for handle event after `UIWebView` is tapped.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you gone through this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115534/add-a-uitapgesturerecognizer-to-a-uiwebview?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107656/intercept-uitapgesturerecognizer-for-uiwebview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115534/add-a-uitapgesturerecognizer-to-a-uiwebview)

Comment: I use tap gesture recognizer but no event happened while tapping UIWebView.

Comment: Also, you should use `WKWebView` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I handle it by putting a button over UIWebView and making this button background color as a clear color, then doing events in this button action.